# Better way to detect if email is from multiple domains

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm doing validation to detect if an email is from a certain domain. However, I also want to have this domain's sandbox environment whitelisted (where the sandbox just has a ".int" appended to it). Here is what I currently have

```
if ( !(email.endsWith("@mydomain.com") || email.endsWith("@mydomain.com.int") ) {
  throw new Error('invalid email');
}
```

Basically, just looking for a better way to check if email ends with multiple domains. I could strip everything from `@` (inclusive) and then check this with some whitelisting array. Or, I could use a regex. Just wondering what others think. Thanks!

Comment: This link has some examples of email and domain matching: https://javascript.info/regexp-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract everything after `@` and check against the whitelist.

```
const mydomains = new Set(['mydomain.com', 'mydomain.com.int']);
let emaildomain = email.split('@')[1].toLowerCase();
if (!mydomains.has(emaildomain)) {
    throw new Error('invalid email');
}
```

or a regexp:

```
const mydomains_regex = /@(mydomain\.com|mydomain\.com\.int)$/i;
if (!mydomains_regex.test(email)) {
    throw new Error('invalid email');
}
```

Comment: for an O(1) test, consider `const mydomains = { 'mydomain.com' : true, 'mydomain.com.int': true };`

Comment: @danh Unless you have lots of domains, the difference is negligible. And rather than an object I'd use a Set.

Comment: I understand, @Barmar, though whitelists are often large.  In defense of an object, it lends itself to keeping the large whitelist in a key-value store.

Comment: @Barmar Any specific reason you use Set? Other than, the assumption that a whitelist will always contain unique values?

Comment: Because set lookup is O(1) rather than O(n).